# JMeter: How to change user defined variable value for second iteration of loop count

Tags: jmeter

I'm running a Thread Group with the following property values:

Number of threads: 200
Ramp-up Time (sec): 20
Loop-count: 2

I also have user defined variables set for the HTTP Requests. However, when the second iteration is reached, I need the user defined variable's value to also change.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Add a [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of first request
2. Put the following code into PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   if (vars.getIteration() == 2) {
       vars.put("myVar", "newValue");
   }
   ```
3. Replace `myVar` with your variable name and `newValue` with variable value for the second loop.

`vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance and [getIteration()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getIteration()) method returns current loop's number.

If you want to dive deaper into Beanshell in particular and extending JMeter test via scripting in general I would recommend to get familiarized with [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-jmeter) guide.

Comment: Are you able to update your answer to also include how to do this with Groovy/JSR223 Sampler?

Comment: You can use the same code, it will work without any changes. Valid Java code most probably will be valid Groovy code so if you didn't use any Beanshell-specific functions you should be able to migrate at no cost. More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)